# How to preserve css class name through GWT compilation?

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder

How to preserve css style names used in UiBinder files (`*.ui.xml`) and prevent them to be obfuscated to something like this `GEMOY02DD3B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@external` GWT specific CSS at-rule followed by list of class names to declare classes that shouldn't be obfuscated.

Documented in [javadoc of CssResource](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/resources/client/CssResource.html).

E.g.

```
<ui:style>
    @external floatingLeft;

    .floatingLeft {
        float: left;
    }
</ui:style>
```

Comment: Important: WIthout the dot